# SQLAlchemy/MariaDB - incorrectly using Windows-1252 and UTF-8 encodings

Tags: encoding, sqlalchemy, character-encoding, mariadb, oracle10g

I am currently trying to migrate an Oracle database to MariaDB. I have a CHAR column in the oracle database, let's call it `my_col`, which I believe is encoded using latin-1.

I have fetched the raw bytes of the column, and decoded them successfully using Python, with:

`my_col.decode('latin-1')`

No error was thrown, which leads me to believe the column is, in fact, encoded with latin-1.

Now, even though the column on the MariaDB table has the latin1 charset, I found that SQLAlchemy was trying to insert UTF-8 encoded strings into it; so I specified `?charset=latin1` on my MariaDB connection string.

STILL, whenever I try inserting the decoded strings into MariaDB, I get the following error:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character \x96` ...`

and at the end of my error trace:

`File "usr/lib64/python3.9/encodings/cp1252.py", line 12, in encode`

This raises two questions:

- why is Python trying to use the cp-1252 encoding instead of latin-1, as specified?
- how can I tell SQLAlchemy to use latin-1 when fetching the strings from Oracle? I would rather not have to fetch the bytes and decode them myself.

Thanks.

Comment: You appear to be using Python 3, so any string that comes back from the Oracle database should be a (Python) Unicode string. Isolate a single string value in the Oracle database that causes your code to fail, retrieve it as `my_string`, and then `print(" ".join(f"{ord(c):X}" for c in my_string))`. What does it show?

Comment: Hi @GordThompson, I have fixed the problem in the meanwhile. The PyMySQL library was using the cp1252 encoding, even when I specified Latin-1. The "x96" Unicode character can be decoded using latin-1, but not cp1252 (easy to check: `x = 'x96' ; x.encode('latin-1'); x.encode('cp1252')`.